# Help me modify this regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

im trying to make a regex, and so far it does the folowwing:

-Disallow whitespace at the front and end
-Allow spaces in the middle

Here is the regex:

```
^[^\s].+[^\s]$
```

I want it to also disallow special characters, how do i do that?

Thanks

Comment: What special characters do you want to disallow?

Comment: All of them, i solved it thou thanks to peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$` should only allow lowercase, uppercase and numbers and spaces except spaces at the start of end of the string